# Moto G auto lock issue

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have set the auto lock for my Moto G if it stays idle for 15 seconds.unfortunately this is feature is not working. I have tired changing the idle time as well, like 5 seconds ,30 secs etc, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you checked the Smart Lock settings?